# Validate input array require only one 1 random fields are filled in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to validate array input from 5 rows fields contain (username, type, request) using a JavaScript or jQuery in condition only one rows is required and it's a random rows. So, Admin can fill it at `Name 3` or `Name 5`, wherever Admin want to fill it.

I was success to validate it in PHP only using `name[]` and `foreach`, but in javascript I only can do it with `name+$i`. But that validation is so different with my PHP requirements.

```
<form action="x" method="post">
<?php for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) { ?>
   <div>
      <span id="username-error<?php echo $i; ?>"></span>
      <label>Name <?php echo $i; ?></label>
      <select name="username[]" id="username<?php echo $i; ?>">
         <option>user 01</option>
         <option>user 02</option>
         <option>user 03</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span id="type-error<?php echo $i; ?>"></span>
      <label>Type</label>
      <select name="type[]" id="type<?php echo $i; ?>">
         <option>type 01</option>
         <option>type 02</option>
         <option>type 03</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span id="request-error<?php echo $i; ?>"></span>
      <label>Request</label>
      <input type="text" name="request[]" id="request<?php echo $i; ?>">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

My jQuery code on `submit` click :

```
$("#submit").on("click", function() {
for (var i = 1; i<=5; i++)
{
   var name = $("#username"+i).val();
   var type = $("#type"+i).val();
   var request = $("#request"+i).val();
   if (i == 1)
   {
      if (name == '') {
         $("#username-error"+i).html('User '+i+' name must be selected');
         return !1;
      }
      else if (type == '') {
         $("#type-error"+i).html('Type '+i+' name must be selected');
         return !1;
      }
      else if (request == '') {
         $("#request-error"+i).html('Request '+i+' name must be filled');
         return !1;
      }
   }
   // else ... no problem here only validate if name selected,
   // other fields like type and request must be selected and filled ...
}
});
```

I can only check the form is not empty for fixed fields ( using `i = 1` ) in Javascript. That's mean Admin must fill it on the first row, so that's different with my PHP validation that can accept input from any rows and only required one row.

JavaScript or Jquery validation rules that I need :

```
1. After pages & form (5 rows -> name,type,request) load
2. Button submitted click without fill any form
   > Alert message (at least one row are filled !)
3. Fill 1 complete user, type and request data on random rows, example row 3 (Name 3)
4. Click on submit again, then success process data
```

[image: Validation rules in diagram example]

So, in validation rules it will have same condition with my PHP, it can be filled on any rows admin wanted to. Not just in `i = 1`.

I have no idea how to check in JavaScript to validate only 1 row of the field is needed and it's a random rows so I can fill it on `i = 3` or `i = 4`.

Even that is use `find('input[name="username[]"]').val())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. JS does not have elseif.
2. Just loop and if there is nothing at the end, give error
3. Give the form an ID and use the submit event
4. Never use name="submit" or id="submit" on a form

```js
$("#formId").on("submit", function(e) {
  var name = "";
  $("#username-error").empty(); // clear errors

  $("[id^=username]").each(function() { // any field id=username*
    name = $(this).val();
    if ($.trim(name) !== '') return false; // stop loop, something was filled
  });
  if (name == "") { // no names were filled, alert on the first
    $("#username-error").html('At least one name must be selected'); // any of them, right?
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
  }
});
```

[Full example - ignores other fields if name is not filled](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/k840qhej/)

[Example that does not allow partial input](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/11tt649x/)